# Creating a data analysis pipeline using (GNU) make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, data-analysis

I'm a scientist analyzing brain data collected from multiple subjects. During the analysis, the data is processed through multiple steps, a bit like a cooking recipe. At the end of the line, there is a step that collects the processed data for all the individual subjects and creates summary statistics and so forth.

As a single step can take up to an hour to complete, I would like to have an automated way to run all the steps for all subjects and compute the summary statistics, without repeating steps that have already completed in the past.

Make seems like a good utility to use, but I need some help with the structure of the `Makefile`. Here is a simplified example:

```
# Keep intermediate files!
.SECONDARY:

# In this simplified example, there are 3 subjects, in reality there are more 
SUBJECTS = subject_a subject_b subject_c

# In this simplified example there are 3 data processing steps, each one taking
# one file as input and emitting one file as output. In reality, there are more
# steps and each step takes multiple input files and emits multiple output
# files.
step1_%.dat : step1.py input_%.dat
    touch step1_$*.dat

step2_%.dat : step2.py step1_%.dat
    touch step2_$*.dat

# Let's say this step produces many output files
STEP3_PROD = step3_%_1.dat step3_%_2.dat step3_%_3.dat
$(STEP3_PROD) : step3.py step2_%.dat
    touch $(STEP3_PROD)

# Meta rule to perform the complete analysis for a single subject
.PHONY : $(SUBJECTS)
subject_% : step1_%.dat step2_%.dat $(STEP3_PROD)
    @echo 'Analysis complete for subject $*.'

# The summary depends on the analysis of all subjects being complete.
summary.dat : summary.py $(SUBJECTS)
    touch summary.dat
    @echo 'All analysis done!'

all : summary.dat
```

The problem with the above `Makefile` is that the summary step `python summary.py` is always performed, even when nothing has changed. This is probably due to the fact that it depends on the phony `subject_%` rule, which is always build.

Is there a way to structure this script, so that the summary step will not be performed unnecessarily? Perhaps there is some way to expand `$(STEP3_PROD)` for all subjects?

Comment: I used to do my own data analysis in this way. Beware. I ended up with a `Makefile` of 190 pattern rules. I had to patch `make` to allow the same rule to be used multiple times in the same chain. I had to do lots of `include`s and `foreach`-`call`-`eval` loops, the latter are totally unmaintainable. The idea was nice, but in truth it was unmaintainable. I never found a better replacement (no doubt many exist), but it became very clear to me that at some point the cost of wringing all your rules into a form `make` will support becomes higher than the benefit.

Comment: While searching for solutions, I've stumbled upon the 'doit' tool. It seems to be a build system that is basically one step up from a simple Python script to support dependency checking. It actually suits my needs quite well: http://pydoit.org/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't overcompilcate things or they will backfire. Try something like:

```
.SECONDARY:

all: summary.dat

SUBJECTS:=a b c
SUBJECT_RULES:=$(addprefix subject_, $(SUBJECTS))
.PHONY: $(SUBJECT_RULES)

subject_a: step3_a_1.dat
subject_b: step3_b_1.dat
subject_c: step3_c_1.dat

step1_%.dat: input_%.dat
    touch $@

step2_%.dat: step1_%.dat
    touch $@

step3_%_1.dat: step2_%.dat
    touch $@

STEP3_PRE:=$(addprefix step3_, $(SUBJECTS))
STEP3_1_OUT:=$(addsuffix _1.dat, $(STEP3_PRE))
STEP3_ALL_OUT:=$(STEP3_1_OUT) \
    $(addsuffix _2.dat, $(STEP3_PRE)) \
    $(addsuffix _3.dat, $(STEP3_PRE))

summary.dat: $(STEP3_1_OUT)
    @echo "summary: $(STEP3_ALL_OUT)"
    touch $@
```

I see no need for tracking `step3_%_2.dat` and so on since they're rebuilt with `step3_%_1.dat` anyway.

Comment: I ended up rewriting the `addprefix`/`addsuffix` bit as (`patsubst %, step3_%.dat, $(SUBJECTS))`